# How to 1. detect url in textarea event, 2: convert to url. Using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, url, richtextbox, tinymce-4

We have a simple control (textarea), where we would like to detect user input of 'proper' urls and:
1. Visually convert these 'proper' urls to links and
2. Trigger an event we can hook on to detect a 'proper' link has been entered.

Of course the contents of textareas cannot be styled. As far as we see, though, TinyMCE (via AngularUI) might be the solution along with its 'autolink' plugin. However, other than whitelisting, it is not clear how 1. we can control/manage what a 'proper' link is (for example bit.ly or deliciou.us, etc are common domains now) or 2. how we can detect an event that a proper url has been entered other than using TinyMCE's 'onChange' and using our own custom regular expressions.

Although we can imagine solutions, this is a common requirement nowadays and we're having difficulty finding pre-built solutions to achieve this.  BTW, we are using AngularJS.

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Mo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a very similar situation where we have a textArea where the user can enter anything and any urls  are supposed to be converted and displayed as clickable links. We solved it as follows.
Display the textarea value in a div. Prior to display we translate the value with a small function like this:

```
 $scope.transformHrefsInAnswer = function(value) {
            var retval = value;
            if(retval != null) {
                var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
                retval = value.replace(urlRegex, function (url) {
                    return '<a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">' + url + '</a>';
                });
            }
            return retval;
        };
```

When the user clicks on the div we switch it to be a editable textarea with the actual value bound to the proper ng-model.  They can then put in anything they want. When the area loses focus it switches back to a DIV and we call the transform function again so it displays as a valid, clickable link.

If all you want to do is validate you can use the transform function with minor mods to check for matches.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Scott, thank you for your thoughtful response.  However, if I understand your response correctly,  this does not allow 'live' url conversion to links and it also does not allow 'live' detection a url has been entered so we can take specific action.  For example, look at Facebook, and how as you enter url's that are not only live-converted to links, the links popup as social snippets at the bottom once the url is detected as well.

Comment: No this does it live. You have to make a choice on how the user edits a link. If it is live in whatever they are editing then there is no way to click somewhere in the link to place the cursor in order to type because it will just popup whatever page you are linking into. You have to have an "edit" mode and a "live" mode if you are using the same text. Hence, when the user clicks in the text they type. As soon as focus changes then the link becomes LIVE. If you detect an improper URL at that point you can indicate such.

Comment: Scott, thanks. By 'live' I mean when user hits spacebar then the urls are converted to links (rather than clicking outside).  Although this can be done through various means, we have come to the conclusion that it's not required.  I will, however, accept your post as a possible answer.  Thanks!